# Import images to Numpy array, then divide into training and test sets

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have a set of 20,000 images that I am importing from disk like below.

```
imgs_dict={}
path="Documents/data/img"
os.listdir(path)
valid_images =[".png"]

for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext= os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    img_name=os.path.basename(f)
    img_name=os.path.splitext(img_name)[0]
    img=np.asarray(Image.open(os.path.join(path,f)))
    imgs_dict.update([(img_name,img)])
```

The reason I am converting this to a dictionary at the end is because I also have two other dictionaries specifying the image id, the classification and whether it is part of the training or validation set. One of these dictionaries corresponds to all the data that should be part of the training data and the other specifies those that should be part of the validation data. After I separate them out, I need to get them back into the standard array format for images (height, width, channels). How can I take a dictionary of images and convert it back into the format I'm wanting here? When i do the below, it produces an array with a shape of (8500,), which is the amount of images in my training set but obviously not reflective of the height, width and channels.

```
x_train=np.array(list(training_images.values()))
np.shape(x_train)
(8500,)
```

Or secondarily, am I going about this all wrong? Is there an easier way to handle images than this? It would seem much nicer to just keep the images in a numpy array from the beginning, but as far as I can tell there's no way to have arrays have a key value/label of any sort so I can't pull out specific images.

Edit: For some more context, what I'm essentially trying to do is get my data into a format like what is described in the following link.

https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python

The specific part in question I'm having trouble with is this:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

# Load pre-shuffled MNIST data into train and test sets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

When we load the MNIST data, how is the relation between X_train and y_train determined? How can I replicate that with my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way of handling image data in Keras. Specifically, when dealing with large dataset you want to use a generator instead of loading all of the images to the memory, so specifically please refer to the [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) class. This class in a data generator already implemented in Keras, so unless you need any special operations etc. this can be the "go-to-guy", at least for basic projects. This will also allow you to define basic augmentations and normalization (for example - rescaling, normalize the data, rotation etc.).

Specifically, you can automatically upload images per class either by arranging them in subdirectoris (put all the images from a single label under the same subdirectory), or by creating a data frame that indicates for each image path what is it's label. Refer to [flow_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) and [flow_from_dataframe](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe) accordingly.

For train-test splitting, the easiest way is to keep your train and test set in different directories (e.g data/train and data/test) and create 2 different generators. For example, a figure from [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) tutorial:

[image: using ImageDataGenerator]

In case you don't wan't to put the train and test data at different directories, you can use the `validation_split` argument when initialize the generator (e.g `validation_split=0.2`), then, when invoking `flow_from_directory`, add the argument `subset='validation'` `or subset='training'`.

Having said all that, in case you want to load all of the images to the memory as you did and just split them easily, you can use scikit learn - `train_test_split`, as described [here](https://medium.com/@contactsunny/how-to-split-your-dataset-to-train-and-test-datasets-using-scikit-learn-e7cf6eb5e0d), for example.

PS

regarding MNIST - this is a well established benchmark, which is strictly defined to train and test set, so everyone will be able to compare thier evaluations on the exact same images. This is the reason it is already splitted in advance.

Comment: This is very helpful, I'm working from a little bit different starting point so I would like your opinion here. Basically what I have is a bunch of image files in one directory with the image id as the name, then I have two csv files (one for training and one for validation) denoting the classification of the images by image id. Is the most efficient way to go about this to try and write some automated program to save the files to a new directory based on their training/validation designation and 0/1 classification similar to what was done in the tutorial you linked?

Comment: If you already have csv files, you can use panda's 'DataFrame' class ('from_csv' methd) to load the csv to data frame, and then use flow_from_dataframe as desribed above. However also copying the images to different directories is OK, it's really for you to decide what is more convieniet for you...